# Select query return null but data is exist

Tags: sql-server, select, encryption, sql-like

i have one query in MS_SQL that is :

```
Select * from Mytable where ColumnName Like N'%My text%'
```

My text is encrypted data that exist in table :

```
cY8QsCeJ9XktaZeHDncE7k1y3Hsq2Zd1FqKM/miW6EktrtWaBZVHvlstBjrx87RyE2+Tbnl+JOEuFTtL5kObCS2lwHKyJtQgmfiyRCmY0WJVwZFN+c4spzanfMAZm8giBnRxtmS3+QmKFXdYX3TbliCCqdP0If5bwx4Vf3n3lvDsLsgyqYH7rMXNcm13iaCaEoi+8MNlAlY=
```

in this situation query return one row and work correctly but when i search section of this code like :

```
cY8QsCeJ9XktaZeHDncE7k1y3Hsq2Zd1FqKM/mi
```

the query return nothing.

how can i change my query that can search encrypted data?
my rows in database table was Encrypted by WindowsApplication app and i just access to database.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the table and the column, such as type, max size, etc ?

Comment: You can't search the encrypted string via the original string. Thats logic on the server side lamguage

Comment: but this string that saved in table is same string..

Comment: i was search Encrypted string as same as that saved in the database.. but i get no result from query

Comment: Column type is NVARCHAR(MAX)